# CSS add seperator after <li>-Tag

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm tring to edit the Wordpress homepage of my friend.
He uses a free Template and want to add an seperator "|" after each of his menu items.

I tried it with this one.

```
#menu-mainmenu li + li:before {
    content: " | ";
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

Format looks like this

```
<ul id="menu-mainmenu">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>    
</ul>
```

The Pipes appear over the

-Tag.

[image]

This is what I want to do

[image]

Comment: Not enough HTML/CSS to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, since you were unable to share the code, I had to simulate the error, and my guess was that the `<li>` has a fixed `width`, so in the first example we have the possible error, please verify if that's your case. If it is, the second example will give you the asnwer.

#### Posible Error

```css
#menu-mainmenu li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
}

#menu-mainmenu li + li:before {
    content: " | ";
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-mainmenu">
    <li>hola</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>cómo</li>
    <li>está</li>    
</ul>
```

#### Fix

```css
#menu-mainmenu li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

#menu-mainmenu li + li:before {
    content: " | ";
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-mainmenu">
    <li>hola</li>
    <li>.........</li>
    <li>cómo</li>
    <li>está</li>    
</ul>
```

You can play around with `absolute` positioned elements as long as its parent is a `relative` element.

One more time, please submit as much code as you can so we can help you out, otherwise if nobody finds an answer it will be a waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

I had to make a lot of guesses here because you didn't include much code or explanation for what you are trying to achieve but I think I have managed to create the overall appearance of what you want.

I have created two ways that this works, one which should work for anyone and another which will work for everyone but work specifically in your case

**Number one:**

```css
#menu-mainmenu li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

#menu-mainmenu li:not(:first-child):after {
  content: " | ";
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-mainmenu">
  <li>HOME</li>
  <li>ABOUT</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

**Number two:**

```css
#menu-mainmenu li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

#menu-mainmenu li.line {
  margin: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-mainmenu">
  <li>HOME</li>
  <li class="line">|</li>
  <li>ABOUT</li>
  <li class="line">|</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li class="line">|</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @TheNewby how about now? :)

Comment: If I run your snipped in Stack it works perfect. As soon I add it in the CSS file of the template it doesn't work

Comment: @TheNewby what template are you using or can you send me the link to the page? :) it must be something in there

Comment: @TheNewby also I have added a new one in my answer that will probably work

Answer (score 2):

I would use `:after` instead of `:before`

```css
#menu-mainmenu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#menu-mainmenu > li:after {
    content: " | ";
    padding: 0 15px;
}

#menu-mainmenu > li:last-child:after {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-mainmenu">
  <li>Link 1</li>
  <li>Link 2</li>
  <li>Link 3</li>
  <li>Link 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Didn't helped :/ pretty much same effect as my code

Comment: When you run the above code snippet does THAT look like what you want? If so; the issue is whatever other CSS you have in your project.

Comment: Yes the snipped looks perfect

Comment: Then as I said above; the issue is some CSS or HTML implementation on your project that you haven't shared.  Can't do much to troubleshoot what we can't see.

Answer (score 2):

Using your CSS example , you'll need the follow:

```
#menu-mainmenu li{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Run this snippet:

```css
#menu-mainmenu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#menu-mainmenu li + li:before {
    content: " | ";
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-mainmenu">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6936pon8/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
#menu-mainmenu li:after {
    content: " | ";
    padding: 0 15px;
}

#menu-mainmenu li:last-child:after {
  content:"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hey! check this out :)

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing : border-box;
        list-style-type : none;
}

#menu-mainmenu li {
       display: inline-block;
       padding: 5px 10px;
}

#menu-mainmenu li:after {
      content : " | ";
      display: inline-block;
      width : 10px;
      height : 30px;
      padding-left : 5px;
      margin-left : 10px;
      background-color: yellow;
      font-size : 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-mainmenu">
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>forth</li>    
</ul>
```